Optimizing Memory Access Patterns for Hashmap
Description of the problem
In my actual use case, I need to perform pre-deduplication on newly generated data using a simplified hashmap to accelerate a subsequent sorting process. The goal is to efficiently identify and filter out duplicate data before sorting (though not necessarily completely deduplicate). So I don't need to handle hash collisions or adjust the hash table size.
However, I'm encountering performance issues, primarily due to its inherent random memory access pattern, which leads to low cache hit rates and, consequently, poor execution speed.
Performance Issue
To illustrate the problem, I've created a simplified test example (see below) where I compare three functions with similar computational loads. Despite this, their execution times differ drastically. The ratios of their execution times are approximately 1:7:7
import time
import numpy as np
from numba import prange, njit

# Function 1: fills an array with hashed values.
@njit(nogil=True, parallel=True)
def test_array(arr):
    array = np.empty(2**24, dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in prange(2**24):
        hashed = (arr[i] * np.uint64(2844674407709551453)) >> np.uint64(40)
        array[i] = hashed
    return array

# Function 2: fills an hashmap with indices.
@njit(nogil=True, parallel=True)
def test_hashmap(arr):
    hashmap = np.empty(2**24, dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in prange(2**24):
        hashed = (arr[i] * np.uint64(2844674407709551453)) >> np.uint64(40)
        hashmap[hashed] = i
    return hashmap

# Optimized Function2: Separates the hashing and storing phases into two steps.
@njit(nogil=True, parallel=True)
def optimized_test_hashmap(arr):
    # First, compute all hash values and store them in an array.
    hash_values = np.empty(2**24, dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in prange(2**24):
        hash_values[i] = (arr[i] * np.uint64(2844674407709551453)) >> np.uint64(40)

    # Then, use the precomputed hash values to fill the hashmap.
    hashmap = np.empty(2**24, dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in prange(2**24):
        hashmap[hash_values[i]] = i
    
    return hashmap


arr = np.random.randint(0, 1 << 64, 2**24, dtype=np.uint64)

# Warm-up runs to ensure JIT compilation is done before timing
t1 = test_array(arr)
t2 = test_hashmap(arr)
t3 = optimized_test_hashmap(arr)

t0 = time.time()
t1 = test_array(arr)
print(f"Execution time for test_array: {time.time() - t0} seconds")

t0 = time.time()
t2 = test_hashmap(arr)
print(f"Execution time for test_hashmap: {time.time() - t0} seconds")

t0 = time.time()
t3 = optimized_test_hashmap(arr)
print(f"Execution time for optimized_test_hashmap: {time.time() - t0} seconds")


test_array: This function sequentially writes hashed values into an array. Since memory access is sequential, it benefits greatly from cache efficiency and executes quickly.
test_hashmap: In this function, the hash value is used as an index to store data in a hashmap (array). Due to the random nature of the hash indices, memory access becomes highly unpredictable, leading to poor cache performance. This results in a much slower execution, despite the computation being similar to test_array.
optimized_test_hashmap: This function separates hash calculation from storage, but the execution time is still similar to test_hashmap, indicating that the results is independent of the possible vectorisation of numba.

Question:
Given that my real-world scenario requires using a hashmap to efficiently filter out duplicate data before sorting (though not necessarily completely deduplicating), is there any design or optimization strategy that could significantly improve the performance of the hashmap, specifically in terms of memory access efficiency? Are there techniques that can help mitigate the cache inefficiency caused by the unpredictable access patterns?
I am not concerned with handling hash collisions or adjusting the size of the hash table, just optimizing the efficiency of memory access.
Additional Context:

The data type to be processed in the actual problem is uint64 and the amount of data is so large that it cannot be put into the cache.
The hash function involves a simple multiplication and bit-shifting operation, and performance good in removing duplicates when the length of the hashmap is similar to the the number of distinct elements.
The primary goal is to speed up the pre-deduplication process to reduce the time needed for subsequent sorting. I'll do another de-duplication after sorting

Any suggestions or insights into improving cache efficiency or alternative data structures that are better suited for this kind of workload would be greatly appreciated.

Does it have to be this exact strategy? For example there's a de-duplicating version of merge-sort (with a fairly reasonable memory access pattern, not random at least) which doesn't require any pre- or post- de-duplication (the duplicates are progressively removed in each merge step)

I'm currently using a very fast simd-based qsort, which doesn't implement a merge sort that includes a de-duplication function. Also if you can reduce the array length to about 30% (in my case) before sorting, it always saves a lot of sorting time. @用户555045


Given that my real-world scenario requires using a hashmap to efficiently filter out duplicate data before sorting (though not necessarily completely deduplicating)

If you want to filter out duplicates before a sort and you do not need to remove all duplicates, then Bloom filters can be more efficient than hash-maps. Indeed, this probabilistic data structure is significantly more compact than a hash-map. The probability of finding a duplicate value can strongly impact the performance of Bloom filter compared to (only) hash-maps. The best is simply to test it in your specific use-case so to see if it is better.
Also note that sorting can be better than hash-maps when the number of value is relatively big and the number of duplicate is pretty low. Sorting can be aggressively optimized in some case thanks to SIMD units (or a radix sort -- possibly a combination of both). Sorting can also be performed in parallel (while this can be complicated to efficiently remove duplicates with multiple threads) though it tends not to scale.

Are there techniques that can help mitigate the cache inefficiency caused by the unpredictable access patterns?

Yes.
One solution is software prefetching. Indeed, the hardware prefetcher generally cannot predict the addresses of the memory fetch so manual software prefetching can help to reduce the latency of the next cache accesses. Note that prefetching is brittle. It tends to be available only in low-level native languages like C/C++/Rust with intrinsics.
Note that in test_hashmap, multiple threads write into the same array. They can write at the same location, or just the same cache line. The former can cause a race condition resulting in an undefined behaviour (eg. possibly causing a huge slowdown, corrupt data, or even a crash of target code). If so, this problem must be fixed. The later can strongly decrease performance due to an effect called false-sharing. Indeed, the cache line is shared between two cores and must move from one core to another (typically through the L3 cache having a significant latency).
Assuming no race condition or false sharing issue happen, each memory write cause a whole cache line (eg. 64 bytes) to be fetched from memory, modified and written back due to the write-allocate policy of mainstream CPUs. This put a significant pressure on the memory hierarchy, especially if the hash map is too big to fit in CPU cache. I think this is what happen your case since your hash-map takes 64 MiB in memory and >= 64 MiB L3 cache are relatively rare: each access to the hash-map results in 2x64=128 bytes in RAM. Some CPU (i.e. Intel ones) can fetch 2 cache lines in this case, which means 2x128=256 bytes per hash-map access. This is huge. As a result, the operation might be limited by the bandwidth of your RAM. Streaming stores can help to reduce the throughput (by a factor of 2). However, they require writes to be aligned in memory and a full cache line needs to be written so it does not really fit your needs.
If your RAM has a sufficiently big bandwidth, a bigger issue is RAM latency. This should be the main bottleneck on mainstream recent PC with DDR5 RAM (especially ones with >= 2 DDR DIMM). Indeed, the latency of a mainstream DDR4/DDR5 RAM can be pretty big (at least dozens of nanoseconds) and it is very hard for the CPU to mitigate it. Having fully-independent loop iterations strongly help the CPU to perform reads as early as possible increasing the concurrency of the memory reads, but this is often not enough to fully overlap latency with memory data transfer. In fact, AFAIK, it is often not even possible for the CPU to do that for random read/write in large memory sections (especially with pointer chasing)... In such a pathological case, the only main thing you can do is to prefetch cache lines at the right time (not too early nor too lately) and provide enough parallelism at the instruction level for the CPU to maximize the concurrency of the memory accesses. This is not an easy task and the best code is generally dependent of the target CPU architecture (mainly because of prefetching).
Last but not least TLB misses can introduce an additional overhead/latency. You should check you use huge pages (typically 2 MiB on x86) so to avoid them as much as possible.
Besides, if you run this code on a CPU having multiple NUMA nodes (like on an AMD CPU with multiple CCD), then you should be aware that access to a remove NUMA node may introduce an additional latency (as well as cache/DRAM load-balancing issues regarding the throughput). This typically happens with you code since 2 cores of two different CCD can access to the same memory page.
If you can, you should really avoid the hash-map to be bigger than the last-level cache of your CPU so to significantly reduce the latency of memory accesses (and fix possible bandwidth issue since the L3 tends to scale well). Sometimes, using multiple small hash-maps (e.g. one per thread) is much better than a big shared one, though it is not always possible to do that. The size of the hash-map item also matter a lot to reduce the overall global size of the container.
Related posts:

The most efficient way rather than using np.setdiff1d and np.in1d, to remove common values of 1D arrays with unique values
How to properly use prefetch instructions?


Can you expand on the bloom filter idea, I also thought about but I abandoned that line of thought because of the false positives (false negatives would be less bad and only require some post-filtering after sorting, but AFAIK there's no "reversed" variant of bloom filter)

My data duplicates at a rate of 3-5 times. But Bloom filters can cause false positives, which is unacceptable. Is there any good way to avoid this?

I ran some more tests, such as making the hash table size in the sample very small to increase the number of concurrent writes. The results show that concurrent writes do affect performance significantly at some lengths, but the low cache hit rate is the main reason when the hash table is large

Pre-fetching requires predicting the data that the program will access. If the elements that need to be looked up are generated sequentially, pre-fetching can be challenging. By accumulating a certain number of elements and then inserting them in batches, could this potentially improve performance?

The link provided in the question contains an example in Numba using (simplified) Bloom filters.

If you need to access items serially in a loop where the fetched item is dependent from the previous iteration, then there is no possible concurrency and the huge memory latency cannot be hidden. There is no other way to hide this latency than increasing concurrency. Since the latency of the (DDR) RAM is mostly stable the last decade and is not expected to reduce the next decade (quite the opposite actually with the DDR5), your hash-map performance is doomed to be slow and stay slow in the future.

Thus, yes accumulating items and then doing batch writes can help since it increase concurrency assuming the CPU can actually see the operation as concurrent ones. I did a test with hashmaps and my CPU was able to do concurrent loads (I did not test with writes but it should be similar). If the code of the hash-map is too complicated (eg. containing unpredictable conditions or too many indirections) or contain any dependency, then the CPU may not be able to do concurrent accesses. I observed such an effect on my CPU too.

Note that if TLB misses are a bottleneck (as mention in the answer), then I am not sure concurrency will help. Besides, changing the DRAM/CPU configuration can help to increase concurrency too (though it is not always possible). For example, disabling 128-byte loads on Intel CPU in the BIOS can help a bit. The exact kind of DRAM can have strong implication on the performance of large hash-map accesses.

I see your Bloom filters implementation. But for arrays that are large and have a high repetition rate (each element is repeated 3-5 times on average). The Bloom filter returns False considerably more often, and for most elements, the overhead of traversing the array to determine if it really already exists is huge.

The data to be pre-de-duplicated is generated in a loop (and in parallel). They can still be partially de-duplicated using concurrent access to the hash table similar to what I described in the example. Then write to an array after the de-duplication. However the addition of this pre-de-duplication resulted in a significant increase in code runtime, significantly more than the amount of computation added. Therefore it is mainly due to the latency of the memory access

Thank you so much for taking the time to provide detailed analysis and suggesting possible solutions. I'll continue trying different approaches based on your suggestions,
